# How to avoid Selection to Hide and Unhide Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using below code to hide and unhide the rows. I want to remove these selections from the code but i do not know how to do this.

**Code**

```
Sub Row()
With Sheet1
.Rows("2:29").Select
If .Rows("2:29").Hidden = True Then
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
End With
End Sub
```

I tried but not working. Your help will be appreciated.

```
Sub Row()
With Sheet1
.Rows("2:29")
If .Rows("2:29").Hidden = True Then
EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be condensed to:

```
Sub Row()
    With Sheet1.Rows("2:29")
        If .Hidden = True Then
            .Hidden = False
        Else
            .Hidden = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

BigBen's suggestion:

```
Sub Row()
    With Sheet1.Rows("2:29")
        .Hidden = Not .Hidden
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh now that is slick!

Comment: Thank you very much @dwirony